# Azure api management api policy terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to implement some api management policies using terraform.
I created a `api_management` and `api_management_api` and so far so good had zero issues, I did add a policy to the api using `xml_content` and it worked just fine creating the `base` policy..but if I want to create multiple policy I get an error that the policy already exists.

I structured my terraform as follow:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  display_name = "Api name ${var.env}"
  name = "api-name-${var.env}"
  path = "apiName${var.env}"
  protocols = ["http"]
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  revision = "1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "base-policy" {
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  api_name = azurerm_api_management_api.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  xml_content = file("./policy.xml")
}
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "base-policy-random" {
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  api_name = azurerm_api_management_api.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  xml_content = file("./policy_2.xml")
}
```

When I apply this terraform I get the following error:

```
A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/ID/resourceGroups/example/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/example/apis/example/policies/policy" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" for more information.
```

Currently in my API policies I have only the `base` policy applied, and I want to create a second policy, e.g named `policy_two`, but as far as I understand is that terraform tries to create a second policy named `base` and this is the reason why it fails. So I was wondering how I can specify the policy name?

I hope I made clear enough my issue and thank you so much for your time guys

Answer (score 1):

For one API, you can have only one "BasePolicy".
This is by design in API Management.

But you can specify a policy for each [operation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_operation_policy) "*operation_id*":

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "example" {
  #...
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation_policy" "example" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.example.api_name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.example.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.example.resource_group_name
  operation_id        = azurerm_api_management_api_operation.example.operation_id

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <find-and-replace from="xyz" to="abc" />
  </inbound>
</policies>
XML

}
```